# kafkadrop: Timeout while connecting to confluent cloud

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-cloud

I launch kafkadrop to connect to a kafka cluster running in confluent cloud:

> java -jar kafdrop-3.30.0.jar
> ---kafka.brokerConnect=.......confluent.cloud:9092

I see error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment. Call: listNodes
, message=Request processing failed; nested exception is kafdrop.service.KafkaAdminClientException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment. Call: listNodes, path=/}
2022-07-31 11:25:45.662  INFO 44652 [ionShutdownHook] i.u.Undertow                             : stopping server: Undertow - 2.2.16.Final
2022-07-31 11:25:45.672  INFO 44652 [ionShutdownHook] i.u.s.s.ServletContextImpl               : Destroying Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
```

What do I miss here?

Comment: Did you forget the SASL properties?